# Does $\max_{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big|=\frac 1 n \sum_{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big|$ as $n \to \infty$? (Convergence of R.V.s sequence $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,...$)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

> $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,...$ are integrable R.V.s that are independent and identically distributed.
>
> Show that the following expression converges to zero in probability: $\frac 1 n \max_\limits{i\le n} \left|Z_i\right|$.

What does $\max_\limits{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big|$ mean? Is it the biggest $Z_i$ for $i\le n$? If so, the law of large numbers state that $\frac 1 n \sum_\limits{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big| \to Z$ and I think it is true that $\max_\limits{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big|$ is equal to $\frac 1 n \sum_\limits{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big|$?

Then we have  $\frac 1 n\frac 1 n \sum_\limits{i\le n} \big|Z_i\big|$ and we have $\frac 1 n Z$ as $n \to \infty$. So since $Z$ has finite values (right?), this has to go to zero? If I am right, how can I write this in a more sophiscated way? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, you should learn to read what is written... For example $Z=\frac1n\max\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|Z_i|$ means the random variable defined as $Z(\omega)=\frac1n\max\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|Z_i(\omega)|$ for every $\omega$. In particular, $Z\leqslant\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|Z_i|$ obviously holds, pointwise, because $\max\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|Z_i(\omega)|\leqslant\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|Z_i(\omega)|$ for every $\omega$.

Comment: im sorry i didnt read understand the question; so does the inequality you gave have anything to do with the proof of convergence to zero? I do not think so because it doesnt give an upperbond tight enough to prove its zero. Can you give me a hint on what to do to prove the convergnec to 0 in prob? thanks

Comment: $\max_{i\le n} |Z_i|=\frac 1 n \sum_{i\le n} |Z_i|$ is an incorrect statement (it's not even correct if the $Z_i$ are fixed numbers).

Comment: To prove the convergence to zero in probability, my suggestion would be to write the statement you are trying to prove (which involves the probabilities of some specific events) then to wonder which tools you have at your disposal to estimate the probability of these events (and there, you should realize you forgot to use a strong hypothesis). Because at present, we are lacking a cogent approach to the question...

Comment: i will do that thank you

Comment: "does the inequality you gave have anything to do with the proof of convergence to zero?" Indeed it has not, I was merely trying to show what an absurd statement in your post should look like.

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon>0$ we have:$$\begin{aligned}P\left(\frac{1}{n}\max\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|,\dots,\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)\geq\epsilon\right) & =P\left(\max\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|,\dots,\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)\geq n\epsilon\right)\\
 & =1-P\left(\max\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|,\dots,\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)<n\epsilon\right)\\
 & =1-P\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|< n\epsilon\wedge\cdots\wedge\left|Z_{n}\right|<n\epsilon\right)\\
 & =1-P\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|<n\epsilon\right)^{n}\\
 & =1-\left(1-P\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)\right)^{n}\\
 & =1-\left(1-\frac{nP\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)}{n}\right)^{n}\\
 & \approx1-e^{-nP\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

It is our aim to prove that the expression tends to $0$ by increasing $n$.

For that it is enough now to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}nP\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)=0$
and this can be done on base of the fact that $Z_{1}$ is integrable.

First give that a try yourself.

---

**edit**:

$$nP\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)=\epsilon^{-1}n\epsilon\mathbb{E}1_{\left[n\epsilon,\infty\right)}\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)\leq\epsilon^{-1}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_{1}\right|1_{\left[n\epsilon,\infty\right)}\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)\right]=$$$$\epsilon^{-1}\left[\mathbb{E}\left|Z_{1}\right|-\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_{1}\right|1_{\left[0,n\epsilon\right)}\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)\right]\right]\tag1$$

The monotone convergence theorem tells us that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left|Z_{1}\right|1_{\left[0,n\epsilon\right)}\left(\left|Z_{1}\right|\right)=\mathbb{E}\left|Z_{1}\right|$$

Consequently the RHS of $(1)$ will tend to $0$ by increasing $n$.

Comment: Simpler (and more rigorous): $$[\max\{|Z_1|,\ldots,|Z_n|\}\geqslant n\epsilon]=\bigcup_{k=1}^n||Z_k|\geqslant n\epsilon]$$ hence $$P(\max\{|Z_1|,\ldots,|Z_n|\}\geqslant n\epsilon)\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^nP(||Z_k|\geqslant n\epsilon)=nP(|Z_1|\geqslant n\epsilon)$$ Then, indeed, use that $Z_1$ is integrable.

Comment: @Did Nice. It is a sort of automatism for me to change $\max\geq$ into $\max<$ but this shows me that it is not always the best route.

Comment: thanks! can i do $lim_{n \to \infty} n*(1-P(|X1|<nϵ))=lim_{n \to \infty} n*1-n*\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x|f_x dx=lim_{n \to \infty} n*1-n*c=0$? c being some finite value

Comment: @jamesblack No. Btw who told you that the distribution has a PDF? See my edit.

Comment: @Did I really cannot find any mistake in $(1)$. Which of resp. $=$,$\leq$,$=$ is wrong then?

Comment: I misread, (1) is correct, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Did Ego te absolvo :-)